# Excel VBA = Workbook.Open("Filename") Error

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, autofilter

I'm trying to run a macro that I can choose an Excel file where I can filter date and copy (in a specific sheet) and paste the data back to my active workbook (in a specific sheet).

I tried various forums about workbook.open errors but still couldn't get to fix my formula.

```
Sub CopyFilteredValuesToActiveWorkbook()

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range
Dim Fname As String
Dim strName As String 'for filter


Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Fname) 'ERROR POINTS THIS LINE

Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Table 1")

strName = InputBox("Input Year")
wsSource.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=* & strName & *", Operator:=xlAnd
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A:K")

Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("A:K")

rngDest.Value = rngSource.Value

wbSource.Close (False) 'Close without saving changes

End Sub
```

Comment: And which error is that?

Comment: method 'Open' object 'Workbooks' failed. thank you!

Comment: And what does `Fname` contain when it happens?

Comment: Fname will be the workbook at which the filter will work... Plan is to choose a file and input box will come out to specify the filter criteria...